# Error when creating Azure ASP.NET MVC4. roletemplatedata.xml file cannot be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I installed VS 2012.  I am trying to create a new Azure project with MVC4 Web Role.  When I press ok, I get this error:

***The project template references by the roletemplatedata.xml file cannot be found***

I found something similar used to happen with MVC2 a few years back.

Is anyone else having this issue ?

Comment: There is a possible answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12686637/444244