# Unable to create MVC4 web role for Azure project

Tags: .net-4.0, azure, asp.net-mvc-4

I tried creating an Azure project in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with a single MVC4 web role in it but got this error message.

[image: Error message]

The project itself after creating didn't contain the MVC4 role I wanted. I only found similar error messages for MVC2 and on my other computer it works fine.

Comment: Using the image of the error is making your answer less accessible to searching. You can use Ctrl-C on those dialogs. Here is the error: "The project template referenced by the roletemplatedata.xml file cannot be found."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **roletemplatedata.xml** file is a file included in each Windows Azure project in Visual Studio (ie: Web Roles with MVC3, MVC4, WCF, ...). You should be able to find it under **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\CloudService**.

If you can't find this file there is probably something wrong with the installation of the Windows Azure SDK (VS2012 tools). Try to uninstall every Windows Azure component, download the latest version of the full installer [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/#) (install the SDK link) and install it again. This should fix your problem.